# How safe is it to open file and wait for change in a C# program

Tags: c#, thread-safety, process.start

In my C# WinForms app, users are allowed to create documents and show them in other programs (typically, Word or Excel) and once users close it (if modified), the file is saved by the app in a specific database.

I use the following code to open the file with the correct default program:

```
string tmpPath = "myTempDoc.xyz"; // extension might vary
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(tmpPath);
DateTime tmpStamp = f.LastWriteTimeUtc;
System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tmpPath);
p.WaitForExit();
f = new FileInfo(tmpPath);
if (f.LastWriteTimeUtc > tmpStamp.AddSeconds(1)) {
    db_store_file(tmpPath); // stores the modified version of the file in a database
}
// ---- REMAINING CODE AFTER CLOSING ---
doSomeStuff();
```

I am a bit concerned with the `WaitForExit()` method. Users need to close the default program for the app to continue. This is ok, but is it really safe?

What if the user (or some process) kills the App during the `WaitForExit`? For sure, remaining code `doSomeStuff()` will NOT be executed so I need to make sure all is done BEFORE starting the process... But is there any additional risk?

I know about `FileSystemWatcher` could be an alternative... But this allows the user to continue in the app without saving changes, which is an additional risk I'd rather not take...

Is the above method safe? Or is there a standard method for letting users modify files in their default program and, once done, retrieve these changes in the database?

Comment: Do you mean that a TaskKill will not release the `p.WaitForExit();`? That would be highly un-expected.

Comment: I am not sure what 'any additional risk' means. What kind of risk are you worried about?

Comment: @PatrickHofman About any risk I might have overseen... Can you see any?